Invalid module ".prisma/client/default" is not a valid package
Getting an error in my main.js file while importing Parisma client.
[ERR_INVALID_MODULE_SPECIFIER]: Invalid module ".prisma/client/default" is not a valid package name imported from D:\clip-sort-frontend\clipsort-electron-app\dist-electron\main.js
at parsePackageName (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:784:11)
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:812:5)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:934:18)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1164:11)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)
at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)

